# How storing functions in static collection will affect the system?

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin

I'm an application programmer. I wrote several Android apps in Java, and SPA in React/Redux. Recently, I started using Kotlin for Android development and entered iOS world w/ Swift.

My experience with React was kinda cool. I liked the concept of reactivity. And I thought it would be nice to apply this concept to my mobile apps. I know there is a bunch of [Rx libraries](https://github.com/ReactiveX) but rather than just gradle-cocoapods-sync-use it, I wanted to find my own way, well for educational purpose somehow. I couldn't resist it. So, after hours of research, I came up with this idea.

Here's the thing:

Let's say I'm getting some json array from the server. then I parse and store it in a static class(or [object in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html)) and I call it *AppContext*

And it has the array of functions, and data itself like this:

```
var onItemsChanged: MutableList<() -> Unit> = mutableListOf()
var items: List<Data>? by Delegates.observable(null) { _: KProperty<*>, _:List<Data>?, _: List<Data>? ->
    for(callback in onItemsChanged)
        callback()
} /* or didSet{} in Swift */
```

Then in UI, whenever I want to listen to the value change event, I just write

```
AppContext.onItemsChanged.add { updateUI() }
/* and of course UI references AppContext.items */
```

This is pretty much all that I thought. But I think there are some to consider.

My question is:

1. What if Garbage Collecter collect the UI object(eg. Fragment) then what will happen if that lambda callback function add to onItemsChanged array from object which gc'd?
2. And what do you think about this idea? and what would you do if you were me?
3. Please don't say "Just use RxSomething"

Thanks!

Comment: If you're talking about Swift there is no garbage collector.

Comment: Kickstarter builds their apps with Kotlin and Swift, and use a reactive library (don't know which). Both sets of code are open sourced so you can see what they did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, `static` fields are not garbage collected. So, your code will work.

However, it's a **bad** practice.

As saying above, your `onItemsChanged` will not be `gc`ed. If you reference heavy objects(suce as Activity), they will not be `gc`ed also, which will cause **memory leak**.

Kotlin is built upon java, and its lambda also creates object except some cases(see [this](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/function-literals-and-reference-to-enclosing-class/416) and [this](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/lambdas-and-implicit-references-to-the-instance-of-the-enclosing-class/2288)).

Answer (score 2):

iOS/Swift does not use a garbage collector. iOS uses ARC, which is a different memory management model also based on strong references.

As long as you maintain a strong reference to an object, it won't be released.

I don't know Kotlin, so it's a little hard for me to follow your code snippet, but maintaining an array of closures (lambdas) is fine.